# Java: Make an array of ints, then make new arrays of the size of each int

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, selection-sort

Edit: Professor helped me with a solution (see directly below)

```
public class TestSortMethods {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array0 = new int[] {10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000};

    for (int i = 0; i < array0.length; i++) {
        int[] array1 = SortMethods.randomIntArray(array0[i], 100.0);
        int[] array2 = SortMethods.copyArray(array1);
        SortMethods.printArray(array1);
        System.out.println("\nSorting array\n");
        SortMethods.selectionSort(array1);
        int c = SortMethods.selectionSortComparisons(array2);
        System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
    }
```

I have no other way to articulate this but to be long-winded, so I apologize in advance.  For a programming assignment (homework) we are testing comparisons for selection sort of different size arrays of random numbers. I can't figure out how to write the code so that "array1", a random array of integers 10-100 inclusive will be created with the length of the first index of array0.  I'm not sure of how to construct a for loop to do this.  Essentially there will be an array of 10 random numbers, and then 50, 100, 250, etc. **My code is incomplete**

```
public class TestSortMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //When completing the last step of the assignment, it's much faster to create an array containing the 
        //different sizes you want to sort (new int[] {10, 50, 100, ...}) and use a for loop to generate, copy,
        //and sort random arrays of those sizes. If you aren't sure how to do this, I'd recommend asking for help. 
        //This involves some basic skills with arrays and loops that are useful to have at this point in the class.

        // make array with different sizes (in excel file) for loop making array which tells 
        //all the different sizes it would be sorting.

        int[] array0; 
        array0 = new int[]{10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000};
        int[] array1 = SortMethods.randomIntArray(10, 100.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < (array0.length); i++) {
            array1[i] += 1;
        }
        int[] array2 = SortMethods.copyArray(array1);
        SortMethods.printArray(array1);
        System.out.println("\nSorting array\n");
        SortMethods.selectionSort(array1);
        int c = SortMethods.selectionSortComparisons(array2);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried write `SortMethods.randomIntArray` yet?

Comment: What is `SortMethods.randomIntArray`?

Comment: SortMethods is the main class.  randomIntArray creates an array of n integers of double range. (int n, double range) So if it were randomIntArray(10, 100), the array would print Array==> 85 17 53 80 24 1 53 35 82 18

Comment: As a suggestion, I'd remove the "original code" here (it's not much different than yours, and adds no value here), add the `randomIntArray` method here, and maybe try to make it a little clearer what issue you're noticing with your current code (i.e. why do you think it isn't working)?

Comment: To elaborate, it isn't working because it is not complete.  Forgot to mention that.  I'm thinking I have to declare both arrays and then have the for loop handle passing the 2nd arrays contents into the first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a quick method that does what you said in your question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arraySizes = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
    int[] arrayOutput;
    Random random = new Random();
    int maximumRand = 100;
    int minimumRand = 10;

    //for every value in arraySizes array
    for (int i: arraySizes){
        //initialize  arrayOutput to the size in this entry of arraySizes
        arrayOutput = new int[i];
        //fill the output array with random numbers based on value of arraySizes entry
        for(int j = 0; j <i; j++){
            arrayOutput[j] = random.nextInt((maximumRand - minimumRand) + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOutput));
    }
}
```

You can see the code executing on the following IDEONE link
https://ideone.com/ruLsNu

this outputs:

```
[33]
[81, 83]
[79, 84, 82]
[70, 89, 9, 72]
```

The code outputs for an array of random integers for length, 1,2,3 and 4 as listed in the `arraySizes` array.